# Honing rod with angle guide?

Tags: equipment, knives

My mother-in-law likes to have sharp knives, but she also has unsteady hands.  She needs a [honing rod](https://www.bonappetit.com/story/honing-rod) (not a sharpener) that has a very firm angle guide of some kind.  Does such a product exist?  I've been searching the web for about an hour and haven't found one.

Things I've looked at that are not this:

1. Whetstones with [angle guides](https://www.surlatable.com/minosharp-guide-rails-with-liners-set-of-two/PRO-391912.html)
2. These little [wedge angle guides](https://www.sharpeningsupplies.com/Angle-Guide-Set-for-Sharpening-Steels-P888.aspx) that attach to a honing rod
3. These [crossed sharpening rods](https://www.knivesandtools.com/en/pt/-lansky-masters-edge-5-rod-sharpener.htm)

1 and 2 fail because they require very steady hands, regardless.  1 and 3 fail because they're for sharpening, not honing.  I guess I'm looking for something like 3, but that has honing rods, not sharpening ones.

Any clues?  Or am I going to need to fabricate something myself?

Answer (score 2):

The [*Dick Magneto Steel **Polish***](https://www.butchersequipment.co.uk/f-dick-magneto-steel-polish) might be what you are looking for.

If you are looking for something smaller than this, there are also some *pull-through sharpeners* (e.g. by [Victorynox](https://www.victorinox.com/us/en/Products/Cutlery/Accessories/Knife-Sharpener/p/7.8721.3)) available that are equipped with fine ceramic or steel discs, so they acutally do more honing than sharpening.

Comment: Trying to figure out if the Dick is only honing, or is sharpening and honing.  Also, whether I can get it in the US.

Comment: @FuzzyChef the company has an website available in english: https://www.dick.de/messer/en/sharpening/knife-sharpeners. On the site you can contact them as well if no shipping to the US is available. On the site the different products for honing vs. sharpening are explained also

Comment: Yeah, it's just not well-explained on the site whether those devices are honing only or honing+sharpening.  I sent them a contact message. I take it you don't have personal experience with them?

Comment: @FuzzyChef: I agree that their suffixes are a not as clear as they should be. Only *action* for "high abrasion" is a definitive description while *polish* "for straightening and smoothing" and *HyperDrill* "for honing and smoothing" is somewhat ambigous (same in the german description). And right, no personal experience. So my assumption was that "polished sharpening rods" should be finer than "ultra-fine cut rods" and probably should not remove (a significant amount of) material from the blade.